# Can I locally install Mathematica's documentation on a USB disk attached to a Pi?

Tags: wolfram-engine

I have a 384Gb PiDrive from which I'm booting buster. I use Mathematica fairy heavily and it would be great if I could install  Mathematica's documentation either locally or access the version installed on my Mac. Both Mac and Pi are running Mathematica 12.0

Since it's not installed by default because of space issues I presume it is possible. The Pi download doesn’t include the documentation so if I just ‘copied’ it to the drive I’ll need to set up Mathematica to look for its documentation there and not online.

Comment: What's the problem to just copy the documentation to the 384Gb PiDrive? Doesn't it fit there?

Comment: Of course, it would but the Pi download doesn’t include the documentation so if I just ‘copied’ it to the drive I’ll need to set up Mathematica to look for its documentation there and not online

Comment: Why not copy it and configure Mathematica? This is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: If software is specifically configured fir the RPi then it a valid question YMMV of course

Comment: OK, you are right, forgot that.